# Problem about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\exp\left(-x\sqrt{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\exp\left(-x\sqrt{n}\right)$$

A. sum of the series is bounded on its set of convergence

B. sum of the series is continuous on its set of convergence

The correct choice is B.

Give me please hints how to solve it! To be honest, I've limited exposure to such series. Mostly, I'm acquainted with power series. As far as I understand the set of convergence is $\left(0,\infty\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$ by Weirstrass $M$-test:
$$
n\,e^{-x\sqrt n}\le n\,e^{-a\sqrt n},\quad x\ge a,
$$
and $\sum n\,e^{-a\sqrt n}<\infty$.

Hower, the series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: How do you know that M-series converge?

Comment: For any $k>0$ there is a constant $C_k$ such that  $e^{-a\sqrt n}\le C_k/n^k$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If the series converges uniformly on some set and at some point of this set all terms of continuous, the sum of the series is continuous at this point.Try to prove that the series converges uniformly.

Comment: I've no idea how to "create" bound on $|\sum_k^{k+r} n exp(-x \sqrt{n})|$, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$e^t>1+t+\frac12t^2+\frac16t^3+\frac1{24}t^4+\frac1{120}t^5,$$
hence the general term is bounded by

$$\frac n{e^{x\sqrt n}}<\frac n{1+x\sqrt n+\frac12x^2n+\frac16x^3n\sqrt n+\frac1{24}x^4n^2+\frac1{120}x^5n^2\sqrt n}<\frac{120}{x^5n\sqrt n}.$$

Comment: Why then not to add the next term and perform the summation over $n$ ?

Comment: Why the next term, exponent $3/2$ is enough ? But I want this to remain just a hint.

Comment: Because the summation will be easier.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: the intent was to lazily leave it to the $\zeta$ function :-)